# How to include a function of a controller inside another in Laravel4 when name space is changed

Tags: php, laravel-4

I have two controller

1. apiController 
   2.LeadController

now my lead controller looks like this

```
    namespace leads;
    class LeadsController extends \BaseController {

        public function AddLeadsHistory(){

                $data['leads_id'] = Input::get('leads_id');
                $data['comment'] = Input::get('comment');
                $data['date_added'] = DB::raw('Now()');
                App::make('apiController')->addCallback( $data['leads_id'],$data['date_added']);
    }
}
```

I am getting following error

> Class 'leads\App' not found

Can anyone let me know how I can use the controller in this scenario

Comment: use `\App` as the class name, that takes it out of the `leads` namespace  same as how `\BaseController` appears.

Comment: tried it now getting `Class apiController does not exist ` actually my api class is inside this folder `\app\controllers\api\apicontroller.php`

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix done fixed it by using `App::make('\api\apiController')->addCallback( $data['leads_id'],$data['date_added']);`

Comment: Oh, I was gonna say the class name is probably case sensitive with the filename..  They dont match.

Comment: problem was the class was placed inside another folder so i had to give that folder name